# mqttjs keep disconnecting and reconnect in main thread, but stable in worker thread

Tags: websocket, mqtt, aws-iot

I am using [mqttjs](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) to connect to the aws iot mqtt by wss presigned URL

In my application, there are 2 mqtt connection, the first one is from the **main** thread, the second one is from a **web worker** thread. Both are created from a same class (MqttServcie), they have the same logic, same everything.

But the one from the main thread keep disconnecting and reconnecting.

The one from the worker is very stable, the connection is never die, it never has to be reconnected.

Do you have any idea why the connection from the main thread keep disconnecting?
And what make a connection ends? (other than connection timeout and lost wifi connection)

In the image below, I end the connection and create a new one after 5 times retrying fails, so the number of request is several, nevermind.

The client id is always random, so it never be kicked off by another client.

[image]

The MqttService class

```
/* eslint-disable no-useless-constructor, no-empty-function */

import mqtt, { MqttClient } from 'mqtt';
import { NuxtAxiosInstance } from '@nuxtjs/axios';
import RestService from './RestService';
import { Mqtt } from '~/types/Mqtt';
import { MILISECS_PER_SEC } from '~/configs';
import { logWithTimestamp } from '~/utils';

export type MqttServiceEventHandlers = {
  close?: Array<() => void>;
  disconnectd?: Array<() => void>;
  connected?: Array<() => void>;
  reconnect?: Array<() => void>;
  reconnected?: Array<() => void>;
  beforeReconect?: Array<() => void>;
};
export type MqttServiceEvent = keyof MqttServiceEventHandlers;
export interface IMqttService {
  httpClient?: NuxtAxiosInstance;
  presignedUrl?: string;
}

export class MqttService {
  public client: MqttClient | null = null;
  public closing = false;
  public reconnecting = false;
  // Example: "wss://abcdef123-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXX%2F20230206%2Fus-east-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230206T104907Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=abcxyz123"
  public presignedUrl = '';
  public httpClient = null as null | NuxtAxiosInstance;
  public retryCount = 0;
  public retryLimits = 5;
  public handlers: MqttServiceEventHandlers = {};

  constructor(
    { httpClient, presignedUrl }: IMqttService,
    public caller = 'main'
  ) {
    if (httpClient) {
      this.httpClient = httpClient;
    } else if (presignedUrl) {
      this.presignedUrl = presignedUrl;
    } else {
      throw new Error(
        '[MqttService] a httpClient or presigned URL must be provided'
      );
    }
  }

  async connect() {
    await this.updatePresignedUrl();
    this.client = mqtt.connect(this.presignedUrl, {
      clientId: this.generateClientId(),
      reconnectPeriod: 5000,
      connectTimeout: 30000,
      resubscribe: true,
      keepalive: 15,
      transformWsUrl: (_url, _options, client) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        client.options.clientId = this.generateClientId();
        logWithTimestamp(
          `[MQTT] [${this.caller}] transformWsUrl()`,
          client.options.clientId,
          this.signature
        );
        return this.presignedUrl;
      },
    });

    return this.setupHandlers();
  }

  protected setupHandlers() {
    return new Promise<MqttClient>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client!.on('close', async () => {
        if (this.closing) return;

        if (this.retryCount >= this.retryLimits) {
          (this.handlers.close || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
          await this.disconnect();
          logWithTimestamp(`[MQTT] [${this.caller}] connection has closed!`);
          reject(new Error(`All retry attempts were failed (${this.caller})`));
          return;
        }

        if (this.retryCount === 0) {
          (this.handlers.beforeReconect || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
          logWithTimestamp(
            `[MQTT] [${this.caller}] connection lost`,
            this.presignedUrl
          );
        }

        // Re-generate new presigned URL at the 3rd attempt, or if the URL is expired
        if (this.retryCount === 2 || this.isExpired) {
          await this.updatePresignedUrl().catch(async () => {
            await this.disconnect();
            (this.handlers.close || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
            logWithTimestamp(
              `[MQTT] [${this.caller}] connection has closed! (Unable to get new presigned url)`
            );
          });
        }
      });

      this.client!.on('reconnect', () => {
        this.retryCount += 1;
        this.reconnecting = true;
        (this.handlers.reconnect || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
        logWithTimestamp(
          `[MQTT] [${this.caller}] reconnect (#${this.retryCount})`
        );
      });

      this.client!.on('connect', () => {
        if (this.reconnecting) {
          (this.handlers.reconnected || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
        }
        this.retryCount = 0;
        this.reconnecting = false;
        (this.handlers.connected || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
        logWithTimestamp(`[MQTT] [${this.caller}] connected`);
        resolve(this.client!);
      });
    });
  }

  disconnect({ force = true, silent = false, ...options } = {}) {
    this.closing = true;
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
      if (this.client && this.isOnline()) {
        this.client.end(force, options, () => {
          this.reset(silent, '(fully)');
          resolve();
        });
      } else {
        this.client?.end(force);
        this.reset(silent, '(client-side only)');
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }

  reset(silent = false, debug?: any) {
    this.client = null;
    this.retryCount = 0;
    this.reconnecting = false;
    this.presignedUrl = '';
    this.closing = false;
    if (!silent) {
      (this.handlers.disconnectd || []).forEach((handler) => handler());
    }
    logWithTimestamp(`[MQTT] [${this.caller}] disconnected!`, {
      silent,
      debug,
    });
  }

  async destroy() {
    await this.disconnect({ silent: true });
    this.handlers = {};
  }

  // Get or assign a new wss url
  async updatePresignedUrl(url?: string) {
    if (this.httpClient) {
      const service = new RestService<Mqtt>(this.httpClient, '/mqtts');
      const { data } = await service.show('wss_link');
      this.presignedUrl = data!.wss_link;
    } else if (url) {
      this.presignedUrl = url;
    }
    return this.presignedUrl;
  }

  on(event: MqttServiceEvent, handler: () => void) {
    const { [event]: eventHanlders = [] } = this.handlers;
    eventHanlders.push(handler);
    this.handlers[event] = eventHanlders;
  }

  off(event: MqttServiceEvent, handler: () => void) {
    const { [event]: eventHanlders = [] } = this.handlers;
    const index = eventHanlders.findIndex((_handler) => _handler === handler);
    eventHanlders.splice(index, 1);
  }

  get date() {
    const matched = this.presignedUrl.match(/(X-Amz-Date=)(\w+)/);
    if (!matched) return null;

    return new Date(
      String(matched[2]).replace(
        /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(T\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2}Z)$/,
        (__, YYYY, MM, DD, HH, mm, ss) => `${YYYY}-${MM}-${DD}${HH}:${mm}:${ss}`
      )
    );
  }

  get expires() {
    const matched = this.presignedUrl.match(/(X-Amz-Expires=)(\d+)/);
    return matched ? Number(matched[2]) : null;
  }

  get signature() {
    const matched = this.presignedUrl.match(/(X-Amz-Signature=)(\w+)/);
    return matched ? matched[2] : null;
  }

  get expiresDate() {
    if (!(this.date && this.expires)) return null;

    return new Date(this.date.getTime() + this.expires * MILISECS_PER_SEC);
  }

  get isExpired() {
    return !this.expiresDate || this.expiresDate <= new Date();
  }

  private generateClientId() {
    return `mqttjs_[${this.caller}]_${Math.random()
      .toString(16)
      .substring(2, 10)}`.toUpperCase();
  }

  private isOnline() {
    return typeof window !== 'undefined' && window?.$nuxt?.isOnline;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do they have unique client ids? Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75360640/edit) the question to show a minimum viable test case so we can see the code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. They do have unique client_id. I updated the question, include the MqttService class.

Comment: @SonTr. Have you found a solution for it? I am facing the same problem as you...

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. Instead, I came up with an alternative solution for this. I had to show the connection status to user, let them know if the connection is dropped and retrying. After retry success, make api calls to fetch the missing data.